# Python : py and pip commands

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip

I'm learning Python 3.8 (on Windows 10 machine) and everything is not clear.

I can read stuff like this : `py -3 -m pip install XXX`

And sometimes I see : `pip install XXX`

Are these commands do the same stuff ? Which one is better ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=%5bpip%5d%20%22pip%20install%22%20%22python%20-m%20pip%20install%22

Comment: `pip` is Python module to install other modules. You can use `import pip` in own script to  managing modules. `pip` has also special function to run it as `py -3 -m pip install XXX`. But to make it simpler there is also script with name `pip` which imports module `pip` and uses it in the same way as `py -3 -m pip install XXX` - so both do the same but they start in little different way. Most users prefer `pip install XXX` because it is shorter to write in console. But script `pip` install only for one version and it can make problem when there is many Pythons installed with own scripts `pip`.